# Why is "MOVQ 0x30(SP), DX" slow?

Tags: performance, go, comparison, disassembly, pprof

Please see the following pprof session. In the treesort.add, line 42, there's an int comparison. I think it accounts for 64% of all cpu time. In disasm the operation is "MOVQ 0x30(SP), DX". Why is it so slow?

```js
File: treesort_bench.test.exe
Type: cpu
Time: Sep 7, 2018 at 3:15pm (EDT)
Duration: 2.60s, Total samples = 2.43s (93.44%)
Entering interactive mode (type "help" for commands, "o" for options)
(pprof) top 10
Showing nodes accounting for 2.41s, 99.18% of 2.43s total
Dropped 2 nodes (cum <= 0.01s)
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
     2.40s 98.77% 98.77%      2.42s 99.59%  gopl.io/ch4/treesort.add
     0.01s  0.41% 99.18%      0.02s  0.82%  runtime.mallocgc
         0     0% 99.18%      0.26s 10.70%  gopl.io/ch4/treesort.Sort
         0     0% 99.18%      0.25s 10.29%  gopl.io/ch4/treesort_bench.BenchmarkSort
         0     0% 99.18%      0.26s 10.70%  gopl.io/ch4/treesort_bench.run
         0     0% 99.18%      0.02s  0.82%  runtime.newobject
         0     0% 99.18%      0.22s  9.05%  testing.(*B).launch
         0     0% 99.18%      0.02s  0.82%  testing.(*B).run1.func1
         0     0% 99.18%      0.25s 10.29%  testing.(*B).runN
(pprof) list add
Total: 2.43s
ROUTINE ======================== gopl.io/ch4/treesort.add in go\src\gopl.io\ch4\treesort\sort.go
     2.40s      4.45s (flat, cum) 183.13% of Total
         .          .     30:           values = appendValues(values, t.right)
         .          .     31:   }
         .          .     32:   return values
         .          .     33:}
         .          .     34:
      90ms       90ms     35:func add(t *tree, value int) *tree {
         .          .     36:   if t == nil {
         .          .     37:           // Equivalent to return &tree{value: value}.
         .       20ms     38:           t = new(tree)
         .          .     39:           t.value = value
         .          .     40:           return t
         .          .     41:   }
     1.55s      1.55s     42:   flag := value < t.value
         .          .     43:   if flag {
         .      240ms     44:           t.left = add(t.left, value)
         .          .     45:   } else {
     630ms      2.42s     46:           t.right = add(t.right, value)
         .          .     47:   }
     130ms      130ms     48:   return t
         .          .     49:}
         .          .     50:
         .          .     51://!-
(pprof) disasm add
Total: 2.43s
ROUTINE ======================== gopl.io/ch4/treesort.add
     2.40s      5.08s (flat, cum) 209.05% of Total
      50ms       50ms     4fcb66: MOVQ 0(AX), CX                          ;gopl.io/ch4/treesort.add sort.go:42
     1.48s      1.48s     4fcb69: MOVQ 0x30(SP), DX
      20ms       20ms     4fcb6e: CMPQ CX, DX
         .          .     4fcb71: JGE 0x4fcbbb                            ;sort.go:43
```

Comment: Why not use if value < t.value { (do something) because you assign flag for a boolean expression, later on you ask what the result is. While you do nothing else with flag.

Comment: I did this to isolate the long running statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is “MOVQ 0x30(SP), DX” slow?

You have provided insufficient evidence to show that the instruction is slow.

---

MOVQ — Move Quadword - is an instruction from the Intel 64 and IA-32 architectures instruction set. See [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm)

The `MOVQ 0x30(SP), DX` instruction moves the 8 bytes of a `tree.value` variable from memory to the DX register.

---

Performance measurement, like any other scientific endeavor, relies on reproducible results. You have provided insufficient information to reproduce your results. For example, where is the code for `treesort_bench.test.exe`, what processor, what memory, what operating system?.

I've tried, but I'm unable to reproduce your results. Add your code and the steps to reproduce your results to your question.